# How to use multiple autofocus for<ion-input> on different forms of same component using Angular

Tags: angular, ionic2

I try out below one code but its not working for me.

**HTML for login page**

```
<ion-input [autofocus]="inputOneAutofocusEnabled" type="text" required></ion-input>
```

**HTML for signup page**

```
<ion-input [autofocus]="inputTwoAutofocusEnabled" type="text"></ion-input>
```

**.ts**

```
public inputOneAutofocusEnabled:any = true;
public inputTwoAutofocusEnabled:any = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `@ViewChild` in `ts` file and `nativeElement.focus()`

html:

```
<ion-input id="login" type="text" required></ion-input>
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild('login') loginElement!: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.loginElement.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but focus is not coming on <ion-input id="login"> with above code

Comment: oh I see, `ion-input` is not nativeElement, too bad